# Protect API can be accessed by Ajex without Login to Active Directory

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-api-management

I followed this example (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad) and selected "OAuth 2.0" under "Setting > User authorization" for the Echo API.

Then, I created an html file with and trigger an ajax call to the Echo API "https://{myapi}.azure-api.net/echo/resource-cached?param1=sample"

I assume that I should received an error something like access denied or no authorization because this API is supposed to be protected by my OAuth Server (according to the example, it is my AD). However, this ajax call return Status code : 200. I don't need to login my AD but can consume the API.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
             url: "https://{myapi}.azure-api.net/echo/resource?param1=sample"
            ,headers: {
                'Cache-Control':'no-cache',
                'Ocp-Apim-Trace':'true',
                'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key':'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
            }
            ,success: function(result){
                $("#div1").html(JSON.stringify(result));
                }
            ,error : function(result) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(result));
            }
        });

      });
    });
```

I have created another API named "demo" manually with mock response. This API returns an json {'sampleField' : 'test'}. My Ajex call receives the json without issu even I have applied "OAuth 2.0" as "User Authorization" in that API.

Is there anything I missed or I misunderstood how it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, JWT is required to block it.

Comment: Assigning OAuth/OIDC server to an API is purely a documentation gesture. This information is used at dev portal in test console so that people can easily obtain tokens to call your API, but enforcement should still be handled by backend. You're correct, to force requests to have a certain identity one should use validate-jwt policy.